# Compiling c with mingw in windows libusbmuxd compiling

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw

So I have successfully got to a point where I am compiling libusbmuxd on windows mingw to use it for windows platform.

However although autogen.sh and configure is done without error

it fails to make libusbmuxd at below . Does anyone have any idea on this? Is there a clear instruction on how to build in windows?

```
$ make
make all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory /home/Naver/libusbmuxd-1.0.10' Making all in common make[2]: Entering directory/home/Naver/libusbmuxd-1.0.10/common'
CC collection.lo
CCLD libinternalcommon.la
make[2]: Leaving directory /home/Naver/libusbmuxd-1.0.10/common' Making all in src make[2]: Entering directory/home/Naver/libusbmuxd-1.0.10/src'
CC libusbmuxd.lo
libusbmuxd.c:46:26: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant
#define sleep(x) Sleep(x*1000)
^
libusbmuxd.c:46:25: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '' token
#define sleep(x) Sleep(x*1000)
^
make[2]: ** [libusbmuxd.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory /home/Naver/libusbmuxd-1.0.10/src' make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory/home/Naver/libusbmuxd-1.0.10'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: This macro looks suspiciously wrong. Should be `#define sleep(x) Sleep((x)*1000)`

Comment: sadly its because of copy and paste issue to stackoverflow. I have updated it to #define sleep(x) Sleep((x)*1000). Error is not concerning that but I have no clue why this is happening at mingw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *probably* (see later*) a local problem on your machine, because looking at [the code](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd/blob/1.0.10/src/libusbmuxd.c) the line is fine. Some header file might be corrupted/broken. You could check `<winsock2.h>` which is included directly above and could be responsible for the compiler error at this position:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(x*1000)
```

So you could for example preprocess the source file (`cpp -E libusbmuxd.c >libusbmuxd_pp.c`) and check the result. (try to compile it to find the new line number of the error).

*) Btw, my `cpp` in MinGW gives me this:

```
D:\test>cpp -E test.c >test2.c
In file included from test.c:45:0:
d:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winsock2.h:15:2: warning: #warning  Please include winsock2.h before windows.h [-Wcpp]
 #warning Please include winsock2.h before windows.h
  ^
```

So maybe interchanging the `#include` directives in the source could already solve this.